# Why can users register via the web without even verifying email?

Tags: laravel

in laravel user can register and verify email later.

Suppose **A** registers at `www.x.com` using **B** email (so that B cannot register at `www.x.com`).
when **B** tries to register at `www.x.com` using his own email he cannot register because the email is already registered or in DB unique.

So how can I prevent this from happening? I want those who can verify email are people who can register.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);` in the `routes/web.php` (see [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/verification)).

Comment: But user stil can register with others email.

Comment: In the User migration, is there ->unique() on the email field ?

Comment: You can't prevent users to register with some email address. If A uses B's email and has access to B's webmail, A can register and verify with B's email.

Comment: if that the case I've no problem because that's is B fault. but let just say A is just messing with B